# Thunderbird with external editors possible?

Tags: emacs, thunderbird, email-client, thunderbird-addon

The known add-on [external editor](http://globs.org/download.php?lng=en) says it is compatible with Thunderbird 5.  But the latest Thunderbird is version 31.1.0 already.  Is it still usable? Or is there any other add-on that can enable editing emails in an external editor for Thunderbird?

Comment: Emacs can handle e-mail without using an external program like Thunderbird, but I don't know if it's possible to integrate Emacs and Thunderbird.

Comment: I'm aware of Mutt and Emacs.  I need to use Thunderbird as an entry point and fire up Emacs only for editing.

Comment: It seems to have broken recently (Thunderbird 31.1.1), where it can be configured but nothing happens when trying to use it (`Ctrl-E` or via the Tools menu).

Answer (score 1):

One possibility is to install [muttator](http://www.vimperator.org/muttator) (you may want to build a later version), and push Ctrl-i when composing to call the editor. The default editor is `gvim`, but you can change the default editor by add the following to `~/.muttatorrc` (create one if the file does not exist):

```
set editor=your_editor
```